# rvalue reference—"An rvalue may be used to initialize an rvalue reference to extend its lifetime until the scope of the reference ends."

Tags: c++

The code below is what i used to test the feature. G++ compiled it successfully but something went wrong when running it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> &&ff()
{
    vector<int> AA({1, 2, 4, 
5, 7, 8});
    return std::move(AA);
}

int main(void)
{
    cout << ff()[0] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
6822576

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.633 seconds
```

Comment: This code is using `std::move()` to cast a local variable (an lvalue) to an rvalue reference. You can't extend the lifetime of a local variable beyond its scope, period.  Extending the lifetime of an rvalue reference only applies to true rvalues, ie of temporary objects.

Comment: The language-lawyering out of the way, you should make the return type just  `vector<int>` and then just `return AA`, and let the compiler do the moving for you.  It's supposed to in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Lifetime extension rule only works for temporaries; while `AA` is a local object and would be destroyed when `ff` returns. Its lifetime won't be extended even it's bound to the return value of `ff` in the `return` statement. `ff()` always returns a dangling reference and `ff()[0]` leads to UB.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing up my confusion! So, the copy operation from the stack(where the funciton's local object is) to heap(where the temporary object returned to is placed) is inevitable, right? Namely, we are forbiddened to manipulate the lifetime of objects in stack?

Comment: @melanv Stack and heap are irrelevant; and no copy happens because this is a reference binding. You're binding a local object to the returned reference. And yes, the lifetime of local object can't be extended.

Comment: Sorry for ambiguous expression. And what I meant is that if we want to use the results produced by a function in the following codes, we need to pass it to the heap before it is destroyed and the only way to do so is  to construct a temporary object using it(usally needs copy). It seems right.